# create a button which send an email with a shortcode (wordpress - without plugin)

Tags: wordpress, email, button, shortcode

I would like to have a button which send an Email (to the person who clicked, personn known because she is loggued.)

I am using a shortcode to do that, but i don’t succeed in good writing this shortcode.

```
/* Shortcode bouton */
function boutoncode($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'lien' => '#',
'couleur' =>'bleu'
), $atts));

$codecode = ' <input class="bouton '.$couleur.'"  type="submit" name="envoyer" value="Cliquez ICI pour recevoir par Email le CODE PROMO" />';

$postcode = $_POST["envoyer"];

if ( isset( $_POST["envoyer"] ) ) {   
   $codemail ='envoi du mail';
}

return $codecode . $postcode . $codemail;

}
add_shortcode('boutoncode', 'boutoncode');
```

I have a problem with the condition.
I don’t know how to write this.

I found somme example like these:

```
if valeur=oui
 $retour=super
else
 $retour=non
end-if

return $retour
```

But i want to have something like

`when I cliked on the button, i have a value
then i return an Email’

when I do the following code, of course the button doesn’t appear and the return return the code (the condition doesn’t work in a way):

```
function boutoncode($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'lien' => '#',
'couleur' =>'bleu'
), $atts));

$codecode = ' <input class="bouton '.$couleur.'"  type="submit" name="envoyer" value="Cliquez ICI pour recevoir par Email le CODE PROMO" />';

$postcode = $_POST['envoyer'];

$emailcode ='
if ( isset($postcode) ) {   
    echo "TEST";
    //  include("send-email-contact.php"); 
 }';


return $emailcode;

}
add_shortcode('boutoncode', 'boutoncode');
```

I am still searching
Could you help me with this ?

many thanks

Comment: okay, the code which works is the following

Answer (score 0):

okay, the code which works is the following :

```
function boutoncode($atts, $content = null) {
global $wpdb;
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'text' => 'Text'
), $atts));

$codecode = ' 
<form method="post" >
<input class="bouton"  type="submit" name="envoyer" value="' . $text.'"    style="
white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */ white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */ white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */ word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
width:auto; height:auto; text-align:center;" />
</form>';

$postcode = $_POST['envoyer'];

if ( isset($postcode) ) {   
    $msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";
    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

    mail("myEmail@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);   


    if (mail("myEmail@gmail.com","My subject",$msg)==true)
    {
        $message = 'ENVOI';
    }
    else
    {
        $message = 'PB ENVOI';
    }
    //  include("send-email-contact.php"); 
 }

return $codecode . $message;

}
add_shortcode('boutoncode', 'boutoncode');
```

I receive Email.....